# How do you set certain spring.datasource properties in broadleaf

Tags: broadleaf-commerce

We are using the 5.2 version of broadleaf with spring-boot (using the tomcat connection pool) and mysql.

If there is no activity for a while, for example over night, it looses the connection and can't reestablish it. I have been reading about it and was aiming the use spring.datasource.tomcat.test-on-borrow and spring.datasource.validation-query properties but they don't seem to stick.

We have set up our other database properties in common-shared.properties like:

```
database.user=...
database.password=...
database.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
database.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/broadleaf?useUnicode=true&amp;characterEncoding=utf8
```

What is the correct way to handle this problem with broadleaf?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry about that; the Broadleaf database properties are not related to those specific properties but rather the ones that you have there as `database.user` ... etc from [the DatabaseStarter project](https://github.com/BroadleafCommerce/DatabaseStarter). Setting `spring.datasource.tomcat.test-on-borrow` and `spring.datasource.validation-query`.

However, it looks like you are hitting the exact same issue that I resolved [in this PR](https://github.com/BroadleafCommerce/DatabaseStarter/pull/2) in DatabaseStarter (like for MySQL that you are using) and [this PR](https://github.com/BroadleafCommerce/HSQLDatabaseStarter/pull/5) in HSQLDatabaseStarter (which is the default you get). So, as long as you are using the latest GAs of Broadleaf (specifically at least 5.2.1-GA) you should be good to go.